# Spring Configuration Class Processor Error with Tomcat 7

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, spring-annotations, cglib

I'm trying to set up tomcat 7.0.57(JDK 1.7.0_71) to run a web application, in Eclipse Luna.The web app involves Spring annotation based bean configuration. I've added the webapp to the server, and tried to publish the server but I get this error:

```
0    [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: com.zzz.BeanConfigForDev
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:371)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:246)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:626)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4994)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5492)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:672)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1859)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class com.zzz.BeanConfigForDev$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$216e920d is not an enhanced class
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.setCallbacksHelper(Enhancer.java:621)
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.registerStaticCallbacks(Enhancer.java:594)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.createClass(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:151)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:108)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:361)
```

There is no issue in the annotations used in the code as the same setup with similar set of jar is working in other systems. With my initial analysis I doubt the issue is with the versions of cglib and asm used. Have tried with latest versions of these jars and also with cglib_nodep but getting same issue. Here is my classpath config.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHvOT.png

On debugging, I see cglib.Enhancer is failing because of NoSuchMethodException while operating on the configuration proxy. Any idea on the possible causes for NoSuchMethodException in this specific scenario ?

Comment: are you importing a @Configuration class into another?

Comment: @MarianP Yes, I've this import in a java config defined in my web project - @Import({BeanConfigForDev.class})

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is causing this problem, but I solved it by switching to Tomcat 7.0.29